# add reusable INotifyPropertyChangedto usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I'm implementing a lot of usercontrols in my new application and since I want the usercontrols data value to be bindable I want to implement the INotifyPropertyChangedinterface.
The implementation of the interface is pretty straight forward but it is tiresome to have to implement the same code in every usercontrol. 
Does anyone know of a pattern that adds the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged without having to use inheritance? 
(I can't use inheritance because custom usercontrols inherit from UserControl)

One way to solve this would be to create a BindableUserControlBase that inherits usercontrol and implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The problem with this is that if my Bindable base is a userControl then all my Bindable classes has to be usercontrols or I would have to implement at least 2 BindableBase classes

I thought for a few seconds that maybe I could do it with an extension method but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Any suggestions for a solution?

This is my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

```
class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public virtual void Set<T>(ref T storage, T Value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (storage.Equals(Value) == false)
            {
                storage = Value;
                NotifyChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you not using DependencyProperty in your UserControl?

Comment: @sir Rufo, thanks! 2 reasonse, a) I did not know about it, it seems to be exactly what I want. b) I'm working in windows forms.. and DependencyProperty seems to be WPF feature